# Replicating colMeans function on every series in every xts object in a list

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to replicate colMeans function. But I get results as a list of null objects. I have produced a minimal example. Plz check my code

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
managers_1 <- managers[,1:2]
manager_2 <- managers[,3:4]
list_managers <- list(managers_1,manager_2)
## running colmeans function
lapply(list_managers,colMeans)
## Replicting the same function
lapply(list_managers, function(x) for (i in seq_along(ncol(x))){               
                                                mean(x[,i]) 
                                                }
       )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should do:

```
lapply(list_managers, function(x){
  vec <- c()
  for (i in seq(ncol(x))) vec[i] <- mean(x[,i]) 
  vec
  }
)
```